# Django querying using array for column value

Tags: python, arrays, django, search

I'm making a search function for my website that breaks the entered text by spaces and then checks each work with __contains. I want to expand this so that I can pass through what columns I want it to check __contains with such as "First name", "Last Name"... ect.

What I have now:

```
def getSearchQuery(search,list,columns=None):
        """
        Breaks up the search string and makes a query list
        Filters the given list based on the query list
        """
        if not columns:
            columns = { name }
        search = search.strip('\'"').split(" ")
        for col in columns:
            queries = [Q(col__contains=value) for value in search]
            query = queries.pop()

            for item in queries:
                query |= item

        return list.filter(query)
```

Issue is Q(col__contains=value) doesnt work as "col" is not a column. Is there some way to tell django that that is a variable and not the actual column? I have tried googling this but honestly dont know how to phrase it without putting all my code.

Comment: I am not sure but if you just change `Q(col__contains=value)` to `Q(col+'__contains'=value)` in your own code, does it work?

Comment: Hmm, that leads to a "too many values to unpack (expected 2)" but it seems to be on the right track

Comment: `query = queries.pop()` will override the `query` in next iteration??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

def getSearchQuery(search, list, columns=None):
    """
    Breaks up the search string and makes a query list
    Filters the given list based on the query list
    """
    if not columns:
        return list
    search = search.strip('\'"').split(" ")
    queries = []
    for col in columns:
        queries.extend([Q((col+'__icontains', value)) for value in search])

    return list.filter(reduce(operator.or_, queries))
```

Comment: I get "global name 'reduce' is not defined". Isn't reduce a built in python function?

Comment: Yes it is built-in function. Which python version you are using?

Comment: I have Python 3.2. If I use the way I have in my code with the query |= item it makes all the query statements but then when I try to filter I get "to many values to unpack". Any idea?

Comment: Probably you are using `Python 3+`. In python 3+ reduce is no longer a built-in function you have to do `from functools import reduce`, updated my answer.

Comment: Right, okay so even with your answer I get the "To many values to unpack". Printing "reduce(operator.or_, queries)" only gives "(AND: COLUMN__icontains, VAL)"

Comment: I have updated my answer, `Q` needs a tuple.. so i just changed `Q(col+'__icontains', value)` to `Q((col+'__icontains', value))`.